# How does Rails convert an ActiveRecord::Result to an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have a model comment.rb and a comments table in my PG db.

If I fetch the first comment in the rails console:

```
Comment.first
```

it will use the following SQL statement to fetch it:

```
SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

And I get my Comment record:
    #< Comment:0x007f973234212b with its attributes.

However, if I execute this SQL statement like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT comments.* FROM comments ORDER BY comments.id ASC LIMIT 1")
```

it will return an ActiveRecord::Result, on which I can call .columns or .rows.

How can I turn this ActiveRecord::Result into the actual ActiveRecord object that I'm trying to retrieve. What does Rails do to output it in the form of the actual record with its attributes?

Comment: Rails instantiates a model instance with the results of course. If you want to know how that is done you need to dig into the source code.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you :)